# Replicating a Row in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I've a dataset in this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'Value': [100, 200, 201, 120]})
```

I want to replicate one of this dataframe more than once and add new `ID` which is incremental. So, the new dataset looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4, 10, 11, 12, 13],
                       'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                       'Value': [100, 200, 201, 120, 200, 200, 200, 200]})
```

I could replicate the rows in the following way:

```
df_B = df[df['ID'] == 'B']
df_B = pd.concat([df_B]*4)
```

But I've trouble updating the `ID` column incrementally.

If someone can guide me.

Thanks!

Comment: added column strated by `10` or `11` ? there is some logic for incremental column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify starting value for incremental new column and add it by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), also add original by [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
N = 4
first = 10

df_B = df[df['Type'] == 'B']
df_B = df.append(pd.concat([df_B]*N).assign(ID=range(first, first + N)), ignore_index=True)
print (df_B)
   ID Type  Value
0   1    A    100
1   2    B    200
2   3    C    201
3   4    D    120
4  10    B    200
5  11    B    200
6  12    B    200
7  13    B    200
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean by something like?

```
print(df.append(df.loc[df['Type'].eq('B')].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[[0] * 4].reset_index(drop=True).assign(ID=df['ID'] + 9), ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
   ID Type  Value
0   1    A    100
1   2    B    200
2   3    C    201
3   4    D    120
4  10    B    200
5  11    B    200
6  12    B    200
7  13    B    200
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly. Since `jezrael` answered early and his answer is also right, I'm accepting his answer. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @Beta Ok then, at least an upvote would be ok

Comment: @U12-Forward - I've noticed that you tend to post comments asking users to upvote and accept your answers. In [What to do with user asking for upvote and accept?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297597/1364007) [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) said "*badgering for votes, bounties and accepts is not what comments are meant for*". This isn't a new user (they've been a member for 10 years and have >1k reputation) so they know when they should and shouldn't vote on an answer.

Comment: @WaiHaLee True, I am sorry for that!